# Getting DOM xss attack for input value

Tags: javascript, c#, html-encode, checkmark

I have a class named **eHelpDhtm.js**, when I am scanning my whole project through **checkmark**, I am able to see vulnerability related to DOM XSS attack.

**I am getting below DOM XSS attack issue:**

Method PopupMenu_InvokeReady of User Guide\Help\eHelpDhtm.js gets user input for the **location** element. This element’s value then flows through client-side code without being properly sanitized or validated and is eventually displayed to the user in PopupMenu_InvokeReady of User Guide\Help\eHlpDhtm.js.This may enable a DOM XSS attack.

The faulty line in the below method is

```
gbWndPopupLinks.document.write("<base href=\"" + location +"\">");
```

Below is the code:

```
function PopupMenu_InvokeReady()
{
    if (gbWndPopupLinks != null) {
        gbWndPopupLinks.document.open("text/html");
    gbWndPopupLinks.document.write("<html><head>");
    if (gbBsNS2) {
        gbWndPopupLinks.document.write("<base href=\"" + location +"\">");
    } else {
        gbWndPopupLinks.document.write("<");
        gbWndPopupLinks.document.write("script>");
        gbWndPopupLinks.document.write("function gotoUrl(aUrl) {opener.window.location=aUrl; close();}");
        gbWndPopupLinks.document.write("<");
        gbWndPopupLinks.document.write("/script>");
    }

    // Close the temporary
    if (!gbBsNS3 && gbWndTemp != null) {
        gbWndTemp.close();
    }else {
        gbWndPopupLinks.focus();
    }

    return true;
}
return false;
}
```

Can anyone help me to sanitize it properly ?

Answer (score 0):

I donkt know if this will work with Base attr but in console destination string is escaped properly.
Add this function to Your code

```
function escapeOutput(toOutput){
    return toOutput.replace(/\&/g, '&amp;')
        .replace(/\</g, '&lt;')
        .replace(/\>/g, '&gt;')
        .replace(/\"/g, '&quot;')
        .replace(/\'/g, '&#x27')
        .replace(/\//g, '&#x2F');
}
```

And then use it in Your code :

```
gbWndPopupLinks.document.write("<base href=\"" +location.replace(/\&/g, '&amp;').replace(/\</g, '&lt;').replace(/\>/g, '&gt;').replace(/\"/g, '&quot;').replace(/\'/g, '&#x27').replace(/\//g, '&#x2F') +"\">");
```

Or

```
gbWndPopupLinks.document.write("<base href=\"" + escapeOutput(location) +"\">");
```

[Live example](https://playcode.io/621418/)

You can read about security on Open Web Application Security Project :

[OWASP](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/index.html)

[OWASP/xss](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html)